# Selenium Webdriver xpath not working sometimes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

My this XPath is not working in selenium webdriver while using with eclipse.

```
WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"registerform201367343215309603094227submitbtn\"]")));
            element1.click();

WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"registerform138887139815309587722027submitbtn\"]")));
            element2.click();
```

Please help ....

Comment: why to use xpath when you have id?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Can you share the html for the same ? I see too much random numbers. Share the relevant HTML for optimal solution.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("registerform201367343215309603094227submitbtn")));
            element1.click();

WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("registerform138887139815309587722027submitbtn")));
            element2.click();
```

Comment: Note that this id contains too much numeric numbers , it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials it is not clear if both your `click()` trials were on the same element or not. Incase both the `click()` attempts were on the same element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element To Be Clickable* and you can try the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'registerform')][contains(@id,'submitbtn')]"))).click();
```